# How to get the Test Configuration name in UFT?

Tags: qtp, alm, hp-quality-center

Recently we upgraded our test management tool from HP QC to HP ALM which supports a new feature called "Test Configuration". Earlier we used to have multiple tests developed in UFT but now we are using one test with multiple configuration. In script level we have used `Environment("TestName")` at many places. But since now we are using single test with multiple configuration, `Environment("TestName")` will always gives the name of the single test which contains logic of multiple configurations.

Is there any way to get the "Test Configuration" names in UFT?